# c# text randomizer {variant1|varian2|...variantN}

Tags: c#, .net

For example I have text like this - "i want to buy a {car|home|etc}". Is there any lib to randomize text? I.e. make 3 strings

i want to buy a car
i want to buy a home
i want to buy a etc

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements?  do you need three strings output, or do you need to randomly generate one of your three strings?

Comment: Can't you split the text between {text|between|delimiter} into an array. Once you have an array you can use the randomizer in c# to pick a random one for you?

Comment: I almost want to say to define a data structure for the sentence then you can easily handle different scenarios. For example "I want to buy a {car|home|etc} but I want to {save|conserve} {money|dinero|greenbacks}. Otherwise it can become a major headache to try and manipulate strings for many unique scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a job for Regex.Replace:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "{(.*?)}", PickRandomWord);
    ...
}

private Random random = new Random();
private string PickRandomWord(Match match)
{
    string[] words = match.Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
    return words[random.Next(words.Length)];
}
```

This will pick one random text.

Answer (score 7):

You could predefine the strings in an array that then generate a random integer using the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class.

```
var string[] data = new string[] {"car", "home", "etc"};
var rand = new Random();
var text = "I want to buy a " + data[rand.Next(data.Length)];
```

Comment: Assume array contains of 5 items, so data.Length==5. data[rand.Next(data.Length)] will cause the IndexOutOfBoundsException exception when darn returns 5

Comment: [rand.Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx)  will return between 0 and N-1

Comment: @sll - np, you made me check the docs again which is a good thing, I wouldn't want to give a broken sample that runs off the end of an array.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you have to create your own words dictionary

After use some randomizer, for example this one: [Random Sentences and Paragraphs](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random-paragraphs-sentences)

**EDIT**

There are could be plenty of other type of solutions, so please clarify your problem to get more correct answer.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String CalculateRandomString(String input)
{
   String s = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('{'));
   String choiceString = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('{'), input.IndexOf('}'));
   String[] choices = choiceString.Split('|');
   Random rand = new Random();
   int choice = rand.Next(0, choices.Length);

   return s + choices[choice];
}
```

Notes:

- Only works if the choices are at the end of the string.

Comment: the line `choice = rand.Next(0, choices.Count)` should be `choice = rand.Next(0, choices.Length);` and can be simplified to just `choice = rand.Next(choices.Length);` that will do the same thing.

Comment: @pstrjds: Thanks. I couldn't remember if the standard arrays used Count or Length. (I always seem to pick the wrong one!) I left the start boundary for readability, since arrays are zero-based.

Comment: np, I always do the same, the confusion is that LINQ adds a Count() method, so I figured it would be good to clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//demonstration
index = string.indexOf('{');

if(index != -1)
{
   string.remove(0, index);

   endIndex = string.indexOf('}', index);

   if(endIndex != -1)
   {
      list = string.remove(endIndex, string.length - endIndex).split('|').toList();
      return list[rand.next(list.count)];
   }
}
```

If you want it to parse every instance, then set it in a while loop that checks if the index is -1 and use string.insert();

This is the function I made for spinable text

```
        private string spinString(string s)
        {
            string  ret,
                    temp;

            string[] spinables;

            int index,
                i;

            Random a;


            a = new Random();
            ret = null;
            i = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                if (i == s.Length)
                    break;

                if (s[i] == '{')
                {
                    temp = s.Remove(0, i + 1);

                    index = temp.IndexOf('}');

                    if (index != -1)
                    {
                        temp = temp.Remove(index, temp.Length - index);

                        spinables = temp.Split('|');

                        temp = spinables[a.Next(spinables.Count())];

                        index = s.IndexOf('}', i);

                        if (index != -1)
                        {
                            s = s.Remove(i, index - i + 1);

                            s = s.Insert(i, temp);
                        }


                    }

                }

                try
                {
                    ret += s[i];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.ToString();
                    break;
                }

                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }


            return ret;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
String[] strings = {"car", "home", "boat"};
var output = "I want to buy a " + strings.OrderBy(en => System.Guid.NewGuid()).First();
```